# How to pass Array or Collection to Laravel 9 Blade component (without controller)?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am trying to componetize this:

```
<body>
@foreach ($users as $user)
...
</body>
```

Into this:

```
<body>
<x-userlist/>
</body>
```

With `userlist.blade.php`:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
...
```

But don't succeed in passing the $users Array. Code below doesn't work:

```
<x-userlist users=$users/>
<x-userlist users={{ $users }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was missing colon in front of the attribute:

```
<x-userlist :users=$users/>
```